# Numpy : matrix of vectors, inversion

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix A of dimensions N x N, each matrix element is a vector of size M. 
I want to inverse A matrix. In other terms I want to compute A^-1 that is the inverted A matrix composed of NxN vectors of size M.

Here is code to implement what I want to do, I'm just computing M times inverse matrix to compute C = A^-1 x B and then I'm checking A x C = B. But each time I'm iterating over the M element of A, B elements to do a matrix inversion. I'm quite sure my code does what I need but not in a clever way...

```
a = np.array([[[3, 4, 8], [1,8,3]],
     [[2, 1, 2], [6, 5, 0]]])

b = np.array([[2, 0, 6],
     [5, 2, 5]])

c = []
# compute c = a^-1 x b
for i in range(a.shape[-1]):
    c.append(np.linalg.inv(a[:,:,i])@b[:,i])
c = np.asarray(c)

# check inversion compute a x c and checks a x c = b 
for i in range(a.shape[-1]):
    if not np.allclose(a[:,:,i]@c[i,:], b[:,i]):
        raise Exception('Inversion ko')
        break
print('inversion ok')
```

I need a mix of matrix operations and element wise operations. But I do not like my implementations. I'm quite a straightforward implementation with less code exists. Let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stacked your matrices along the first dimension, instead of the last, you can invert them all in one single `np.linalg.pinv()` call. Afterwards use `np.einsum()` to do all dot products in one go:

```
a = a.transpose(2, 0, 1)
b = b.transpose()

np.einsum('fmn,fm->fn', np.linalg.inv(a), b)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `np.linalg.inv` on the 3D array `a` after pushing the last axis to the front. Then, we can leverage `einsum` for the final output for a vectorized way -

```
p = np.linalg.inv(a.transpose(2,0,1))
c = np.einsum('ijk,kli->ij',p,b)[...,None]
```

A simpler alternative to get the final output `c` would be with `np.matmul/@-operator` -

```
c = p@b.transpose(2,0,1)
```

Thus, the whole process could be converted to a one-liner -

```
c = np.linalg.inv(a.transpose(2,0,1))@b.transpose(2,0,1)
```